# Disable Customize Notification for an application in systray

Tags: c#

I have a  C# application which gives an icon in the windows systray. So once the application is minimized it can be retrieved by double clicking the **systray** icon. The problem is that, if the user sets the property of the icon to **'Hide'** from the **'Customize Notification Items'**, which can be selected by right clicking on the Taskbar, he will not be able to see the application again. Is there a workaround that , the **user does not get my applications icon in the customization area**. Or even if the icon is available, **he should not be able to set the property to *'Hide'*.**

Comment: "So once the application is minimized it can be retrieved by double clicking the systray icon" -- What's wrong with a normal window? That, when it's minimized, can be retrieved by single-clicking the taskbar icon? No systray hacks needed.

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately, developers don't get to decide this. It's a user configured option that you shouldn't try to work around as it will just aggravate your users. It's similar to the often asked question "[how can i pin my application to the start menu](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030903-00/?p=42673)". The user is supposed to decide which applications are worthy of pinning and which notification icons he/she doesn't want to see.

Answer (score 0):

You could eventually try to set a different title to that notification every time. This way, the user will need to set the icon not to show every time. The user might get frustrated, though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Vista fixed that bug. I know Windows 7 doesn't show icons I've hidden due to their text changing. I think it applies the setting to the exe that created the icon.